# [[stitchable]] Metal core image CIKernel fails

Tags: ios, core-image, metalkit

It looks like `[[stitchable]]` Metal Core Image kernels fails to either link on compile time due to Core Image `sampler.coord()` and `sampler.sample(coord)` symbols not found, OR, fails to load at run time if I add other Metal linker flags `-fcikernel` (which is not anyways required for stitchable kernels).

Here is the full link of test project on [github](https://github.com/dsharma/StitchableCIKernelTesting). Feel free to download it and play around.

I found the main culprit is this line in Metal file which linker can not resolve:

```
 float2 srcCoord = inputImage.coord();
```

Excerpts from my code:

```
import CoreImage

class FilterTwo: CIFilter {
var inputImage: CIImage?
var inputParam: Float = 0.0

static var kernel: CIKernel = { () -> CIKernel in
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default",
                            withExtension: "metallib")!
   let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

    let kernelNames = CIKernel.kernelNames(fromMetalLibraryData: data)
    NSLog("Kernels \(kernelNames)")
   return try! CIKernel(functionName: "secondFilter", fromMetalLibraryData: data) //<-- This fails!
}()

override var outputImage : CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return FilterTwo.kernel.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, roiCallback: { (index, rect) in
        return rect }, arguments: [inputImage])
}
```

}

Here is the Metal file:

```
 #include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h> // includes CIKernelMetalLib.h

 using namespace metal;

 [[ stitchable ]] half4 secondFilter (coreimage::sampler inputImage, coreimage::destination dest)
{
   float2 srcCoord = inputImage.coord();
   half4 color =  half4(inputImage.sample(srcCoord));

   return color;
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
       class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let filter = FilterTwo()
    filter.inputImage = CIImage(color: CIColor.red)
    let outputImage = filter.outputImage!
    
    NSLog("Output \(outputImage)")
}

}
```

And the output:

```
     StitchableKernelsTesting/FilterTwo.swift:15: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=CIKernel Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={CINonLocalizedDescriptionKey=Function does not exist in library data. …•∆}
   Kernels []

   reflect Function 'secondFilter' does not exist.
```

Comment: What’s the name of the Metal file? Did you remove any custom build rules for `.ci.metal` files?

Comment: @FrankRupprecht It's plain `.metal` file without .ci suffix. Feel free to download sample project [here](https://github.com/dsharma/StitchableCIKernelTesting). The issue seems to be sampler.coord() symbol not resolved. And yes, there are no build rules in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the build process is much easier with `[[ stitchable ]]` CI kernels, you still need to tell the Metal linker to link against Core Image. This was mentioned in the [WWDC21 session about the topic](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10159?time=335).

To do so, you need to add the `-framework CoreImage` flag to *Other Metal Linker Flags* as below. Note that you need to add it in two separate lines, otherwise it won't work.

[image]

Comment: OMG, the words `-framework` and `CoreImage` need to be on different lines when adding (+). That is very nonintuitive, I was adding them together in a single line that was causing build failures.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I saw that Xcode added "" around the entry and that it showed as `-framework\ CoreImage` in the build log. Splitting the line solved that problem.

Comment: where is this located exactly? I can't find Other Metal Linker Flags

Comment: @fontno Hmm, it might only show when you have Metal files in your target? Otherwise, click the + on the top left and add the user-defined setting `MTLLINKER_FLAGS`.